# PHP Determine If Monday or Thursday is next from date provided

Tags: php, date, datetime

Is PHP able to determine if a Monday or Thursday comes next and what the date ('YYYY-MM-DD') will be if I provide it with a date to start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next monday or thursday is the smaller of the two. If DateTime is used instead of DateTimeImmutable, copies (clone) from $start must be used.

```
$start = new DateTime('2022-11-19');
$nextMondayOrThursday = Min(
  (clone $start)->modify("next monday"),
  (clone $start)->modify("next thursday")
);

echo $nextMondayOrThursday->format('l, d F Y');
//Monday, 21 November 2022
```

Try self: https://3v4l.org/Y5sE5

A solution that specifies the short form of the days of the week in an array offers more flexibility. In this way, 3 or more days of the week can also be specified.

```
$start = date_create('2022-11-20');
$next = ['Mon','Thu','Fri'];

while(!in_array($start->modify('+1 Day')->format('D'),$next));

echo $start->format('l, d F Y');
```

It is recommended to ensure that the while loop does not run indefinitely by validating $next.

Future times such as next Monday or next Thursday can also be conveniently encoded as a string using [cron syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). For Monday or Thursday 00:00 the string is:

```
'0 0 * * 1,4'
```

The days of the week are written as digits from 0 for Sunday to 6 for Saturday. A big advantage is that these strings can easily be stored anywhere like in a database. There are a number of solutions to implement it in PHP (e.g. [cron-expression](https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression)). Just an example using the [Jspit\Dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) class:

```
use Jspit\Dt;

$cron = '0 0 * * 1,4'; 
$date = Dt::create('2022-11-21')->NextCron($cron);
//"2022-11-24 00:00:00.000000"
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me future proof this.  This is part of the cron job for creating new editions of the word game I'll be marketing to serve the disabled, elderly and those living with a chronic illness.

Comment: I added notes about the cronjob keyword to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the date of the next Monday and Thursday using a given date:

```
$start = new DateTimeImmutable('2023-01-08');
$monday = $start->modify("next monday");
$thursday = $start->modify("next thursday");
```

Using `diff` with an `if` statement display the result

```
if ( ($start->diff($monday)->days < $start->diff($thursday)->days ) ) {
    echo "monday";
} else {
    echo "thursday";
}
```